# What is the relationship between map-reduce and nosql?

Tags: database, mapreduce

I want to use `nosql` for my application. The purpose of `nosql` is to store user log data, to use and analyze the data, and to provide customized data to users. Here we came to know about map-reduce in search of algorithm and method to process large amount of log data quickly.

**I have a few questions:**

> 1. Is map-reduce an algorithm?
> 2. Is map-reduce suitable for fast processing of large amounts of data?
> 3. How can I use nosql in addition to map-reduce for faster speed?
> 4. I know that mongodb supports map-reduce, is that correct?

I do not understand exactly the relationship between nosql and map-reduce.

Thanks.

Comment: have added answer to your queries. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. NoSQL = [Not only SQL] database are the types of databases  that can
   have structural, semi-structural(XML, json) or non-structural
   data(textual data).
2. Yes it can help for processing large data sets.
3. Where as Map-reduce is an algorithm. Please read this [article](https://www.edureka.co/blog/mapreduce-tutorial/)
   to understand how map reduce works in NoSQL or big data
   applications.

**EDIT**

[Here is some good resource for learning mapReduce & Big Data technologies.](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW9fS654SCO4tXO2lG5x54g) BTW these tutorials are in hindi.

Answer (score 0):

> Is map-reduce an algorithm?

`MapReduce` is not exactly an algorithm, rather a tool which can be used with many algorithm, which make a good "fit". `Mapreduce` leverage the features of hadoop distributed data storage and processing. As you may have notice, not all the algorithm can be "efficiently" implemented using `mapreduce`. So, a design decision should be made based on various factors like data volume, processing restrictions etc.

> Is map-reduce suitable for fast processing of large amounts of data?

`mapreduce` does a lot of disk I/O during its processing and hence is not suitable for the cases, where execution time is a constraint. You may want to switch to `spark` for faster processing. Using `tez` engine with `mapreduce` is another option. However, do not compare `mapreduce` performance with nosql database like `hbase`. `mapreduce` and `nosql` both belong to two entirely different technology stack.

> How can I use nosql in addition to map-reduce for faster speed?

It depends on your use case. It is very common to process `hbase` data into a `mapreduce` program to produce analytical results.

> I know that mongodb supports map-reduce, is that correct?

Let me re-phrase it. `mapreduce` is a tool for which `mongodb` may be a data source.

Comment: Thanks gyan!
I am well acquainted with mapreduce!
But how about using index in nosql to sort large amounts of data? Is mapreduce more suitable for indexing than indexing?

Comment: I know about `hbase`, which is already indexed by `key` and stored in sorted key order. You may use `mapreduce` for an indexing data from any datasource (including nosql) and use the indexed data further.